# UIImagePickerController to pick from Album in landscape only iPhone/iPad app

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller, landscape

I find a lot of articles when googling this but none seem to really cover this case so I will try to be very specific.
I have a Landscape only app for both iPhone and iPad. I am trying to let the user pick an image from his album with the following code:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
context.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
    () -> Void in

})
```

I am using the Popover presentation style because [Apple mentions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) that on iPad this is how it must be set otherwise an exception will be thrown:

> The table indicates that on iPad, if you specify a source type of
>   photoLibrary or savedPhotosAlbum, you must present the image picker
>   using a popover controller (to learn how to do this, see
>   UIPopoverPresentationController). If you attempt to present an image
>   picker modally (full-screen) for choosing among saved pictures and
>   movies, the system raises an exception.

This fails with the below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
```

What I have tried:

- Subclass UIImagePickerController and UIViewController to support Landscape orientation and set shouldAutorotate to false, but I think this is useless as the class failing here is PUUIAlbumListViewController
- Set my app to support Portrait, this works but then the whole app autotorates with the phone and this is not meant to happen
- Use an intermediate UIPopoverPresentationController but never got this to show anything

**UPDATE**
Not an answer, but as crazy as it may seem I don't think this is doable. Thanks Apple for providing a state of the art API in which everything makes sense.
I ended up using [DKImagePickerController](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DKImagePickerController), does the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well with an app that enforced landscape. The only option is to relent and allow the image picker to come up as a portrait, since that is its default position upon being presented.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your navigation controller and change for landscape orientation mask. And then show from that NavigationController your Image Picker controller.

```
class CustomNavigation: UINavigationController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


}
```